# Формирование динамического запроса к БД на стороне пользователя

Tags: php, sql

Запрос нужен для формирования отчётов по необходимым критериям. Сейчас на сайте имеется строчка вида

> `Выбрать` выпадающий список: `участников, секретарей и т.п` у которых `есть/нет` выпадающий список: `условия`.

Но для более сложных отчётов такое формирование запроса не подойдёт. *Как можно исправить это так, чтобы была возможность сделать более сложные отчёты?* К примеру выборка из нескольких таблиц по нескольким условиям, выборка каких-либо значений из промежутка дат и т.п.

Конечно можно предварительно сделать несколько запросов и вывести их списком для выбора, но всё равно необходимо сделать подобный интерактив, если не будет нужного запроса среди представленных.

Comment: Думаю вы приблизились к сложности самого программирования. Как всем казалось то что главное понимание. Увы придется делать всё вручную компоновать и усложнять (конструировать)  всё что вы хотите.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, Да. Это понятно, как сделать на серверной части, но как хотя бы примерно реализовать это на стороне  пользователя?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/98752/ и дальше копать интернеты

Comment: Уважаемый, в смысле как это сделать на стороне пользователя? Клиент-серверное взаимодействие вам о чем либо говорит? Или же вы хотите какую-то автоматизацию для отчетов. Вопрос увы, бесполезный.

Comment: @Borislav, вопрос не о клиент-серверном взаимодействии, а о том как сделать формирование _сложных_ запросов к БД на основе выбора пользователя. Сейчас возможны только простые запросы

Comment: Опишите, в чем именно сложность и вам помогут. Вы описали какую-то недо-абстракцию, то есть, по факту, мы должны догадаться о структуре таблиц и реляций в вашей бд.

Comment: У вас должна быть сущность юзера, которая вяжется с зависимыми сущностями, которые необходимо выбрать в запросе, получаете id, ну или что-то для идентификации юзера, динамически подставляете в запрос, и тянете необходимые данные. Попробуйте, покажите результат и более подробно опишите проблему, в которую уткнетесь, думаю это будет лучший вариант, чтобы вам дали целесообразный ответ, а не лили сюда воду. (Если проблема в самом запросе, покажите структуру таблиц и реляций).